# How to perform an action after branch merge/close in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, resource-cleanup, feature-branch

I want to be able to create and deploy a web application when a feature branch is created from a linked Git repository in Azure Devops and then remove the site and files when the branch is closed.

Creating a new site is straightforward using calculated values to deploy to unique folders, but how would I start to trigger cleanup tasks when a feature branch is merged and closed no longer going to be used?

Comment: Hi, Are you trying to trigger the cleanup  tasks in the azure pipeline? Did you check out below answer? How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [service hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops) to subscribe to the event "Pull request merge attempted". With the [webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops) you can send a notification to an http endpoint (for example an Azure function) that can host the cleanup logic:

> Webhooks provide a way to send a JSON representation of an event to
> any service. All that is required is a public endpoint (HTTP or
> HTTPS).

When you subscribe to the `Pull Request merge attempted` an event of type [git.pullrequest.merged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops#pull-request-merge-commit-created) is sent to the endpoint for the repositories that matches the criterias in the service hook trigger:

[image]